# Json RPC returns bad response if contains Cyrillic symbols

Tags: java, json, json-rpc

I send Json RPC request in simple HTTP Client in IntellijIdea

```
POST http://localhost:8080/endpoint
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "getSomething",
  "id": 1,
  "params": {
    "param1": "1"
  }
}
```

It's valid request supposed to return error
But error description contains Cyrillic symbols and it returns something like this:

```
...
"error":"ÐÐ¾Ð»ÑÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐµÐ»Ñ Ñ ÑÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½ÑÐ¼ Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð¼ Ð½Ðµ Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ð´ÐµÐ½"
...
```

I understand that it is something with encoding, but i don't know how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Setting content-type of AutoJsonRpcServiceImplExporter (when bean creating) to "application/json-rpc;charset=UTF-8" fixed the problem
May be it will help somebody